# Can C++ compiler assume a const bool & value will not change?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, language-lawyer, side-effects

Can the C++ compiler assume a 'const bool &' value will not change?

For example, imagine that I have a class:

```
class test {
public:
  test(const bool &state)
    : _test(state) {
  }

  void doSomething() {
    if (_test) {
      doMore();
    }
  }
  void doMore();

private:
  const bool &_test;
};
```

And I use it as follows:

```
void example() {
  bool myState = true;
  test myTest(myState);

  while (someTest()) {
    myTest.doSomething();
    myState = anotherTest();
  }
}
```

Is it allowed by the standard for the compiler to assume _test's value will not change.

I think not, but just want to be certain.

Comment: I guess the constructor should rather accept a non-const reference. You are at risk of binding the reference to a temporary, whose life-time ends with the constructor call and using a dangling reference in `doSomething`

Comment: @UncleBens - or even better pointer-to-const, which prevents the caller accidentally referring to a temporary, but still lets them easily refer to an object that really is const, or that they have by const reference. With effort they can of course still get a pointer to a temporary, but making that effort puts the fault on them: `template <typename T> const T* blow_leg_off(const T &t) { return &t; }`, `test myTest(blow_leg_off(true));`. Just initializing a const reference member is fraught with peril, you could accidentally get an implicit conversion, so maybe use a pointer for the member too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Just because *your* reference (or pointer) is a `const` does not stop someone else from having a non-`const` reference. Like this:

```
int main(void) {
  bool myState = true;
  test myTest(myState);
  std::cout << myTest.getState() << std::endl;
  myState = false;
  std::cout << myTest.getState() << std::endl;
}
```

Or even more simply:

```
bool a = true;
const bool& b = a;
a = false; // OK
b = true; // error: assignment of read-only reference ‘b’
```

Comment: And don't forget the ominous `const_cast` or, for more complicated objects, the `mutable` attributes and their mis-uses.

Answer (score 5):

`const Type & r` means that "the value of `r` cannot be changed *through this reference to it*" - but it may well be changed by other code that has direct access to the referenced value (or through a non-const reference or pointer). The same goes for a `const Type * p`: "the value that `p` points to cannot be changed *through this pointer to it*.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, it can't assume that, because the value of the referand of `_test` might be modified in the implementation of `doMore`, which is unavailable at compile-time. Since in this case `myState` is not a const object, it's valid (for example) for `doMore` to cast away const and modify it. Note valid, not advisable ;-)

And in general, `doMore` might call functions that have other pointers/references to the same `bool` object by another route. In your example there are no other references taken, so *if* the compiler can see all the code that might possibly reference it (including the definition of `doMore`), and none of it modifies the value, *then* it can make the assumption.